How to solve connection refused on hashicorp vault in EKS cluster
I've installed hashicorp vault using helm on EKS cluster. and the values.yaml find as below
server:
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health"

  extraSecretEnvironmentVars:
    - envName: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      secretName: kms-creds
      secretKey: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - envName: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      secretName: kms-creds
      secretKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

  config: |
    ui = true

    seal "awskms" {
      region = "us-east-1"
      kms_key_id = "8f583ea2-3044-4b1f-97cc-xx8a6xxxx"
    }

    listener "tcp" {
      tls_disable = 1
      address = "[::]:8200"
      cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
    }

    storage "consul" {
      path = "vault/"
      address = "HOST_IP:8500"
    }



secret is created and I can verify it's there. When I try to initialize with the command
kubectl exec -n vault vault-0 -- vault operator init -key-shares=1 -key-threshold=1 
and also checking the events
I get the following
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  70s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned vault/vault-0 to ip-10-0-1-200.ec2.internal
  Normal   Pulled     70s                kubelet            Container image "hashicorp/vault:1.17.2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    70s                kubelet            Created container vault
  Normal   Started    70s                kubelet            Started container vault
  Warning  Unhealthy  0s (x14 over 65s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.0.1.242:8200/v1/sys/health": dial tcp 10.0.1.242:8200: connect: connection refused

➜  maos-project-infra git:(40-setup-hashicorp-vault) kubectl -n vault exec -ti vault-0 -- vault operator init
Get "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused

I've tried everything and am stuck. Need some help here. Thank you.

The events show what happened: the readiness probe failed. This likely means that your pod has failed to start. Use kubectl logs to get the actual log of what happened.
